# How to define a variable's value at the top of a macro and use it in the macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to type a "file name" at the top of the macro and have this 'name' used in the macro. (I did some Access database work so I'm using that VBA code here.)

```vb
// current macro begin
Sub TR_Weight_031023()
'
' TR_Weight_tracker_SAVE_111422 Macro

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ChDir "D:\Dropbox\G_emiguy_052921\__Twix and Rolo"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "D:\Dropbox\G_emiguy_052921\__Twix and Rolo\TR - weight after 031023.xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "D:\Dropbox\G_emiguy_052921\__Twix and Rolo\TR - weight after 031023.pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "D:\Dropbox\G_emiguy_052921\__Twix and Rolo\TR - weight after 031023.xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    Range("O5:P6").Select
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
//current macro end
```

My thought process

1. Define a text string (is that right?) as 'file name' at the top of the macro. Currently the 'file name' is "TR - weight after 031023"  --BUT-- I typed this into the macro.
2. Type a NEW name into the 'file name' string (or whatever type? text??) and have this NEW name be used in place of the current "TR - weight after 031023"

Doing so would allow me to choose any name (ex, "TR - weight sent to Jim") and the file would be that new name. If I make the VBA code / macro longer, I only have to change the 'file name' value.

I envision

```vb
** begin NEW macro with attempt to change
Sub TR_new_weight()

Dim file_name as string
file_name = "TR_new_file_name"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ChDir "D:\Dropbox\G_emiguy_052921\__Twix and Rolo"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "D:\Dropbox\G_emiguy_052921\__Twix and Rolo\"&'TR_new_file_name'&".xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "D:\Dropbox\G_emiguy_052921\__Twix and Rolo\"&'TR_new_file_name'&".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "D:\Dropbox\G_emiguy_052921\__Twix and Rolo\"&'TR_new_file_name'&".xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    Range("O5:P6").Select
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

** end NEW macro with attempt to change
```

Comment: Should be fine without the `'` around `TR_new_file_name`  FYI no need for `ChDir` when you're using the full path and not just the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Using an Input Box to enter the new name

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TR_new_weight()
    
    Const FOLDER = "D:\Dropbox\G_emiguy_052921\__Twix and Rolo\" ' include \ at end
    Const DEFAULTNAME = "TR_new_file_name"
    
    ' enter filename
    Dim file_name
    file_name = InputBox("Enter File Name: ", "Folder " & FOLDER, DEFAULTNAME)
    If file_name = "" Then Exit Sub
    file_name = FOLDER & file_name
    
    ' save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=file_name & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, _
            CreateBackup:=False
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Filename:=file_name & ".pdf", Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        .SaveAs Filename:=file_name & ".xlsm", _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
        Range("O5:P6").Select
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox "Files created", vbInformation
End Sub
```